# Toggle unchecked button is not closing the Socket. QGIS

Tags: python

I have a QGIS python plugin which works fine when toggle button is checked but when i unchecked it then its not closing the socket why?

**here is my code**

```
def show_markers(self):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostbyname('192.168.225.12')
    s.connect((host, port))
    scale=0
    while True:

        if self.iconAction.isChecked():
            print ('Checked')
            m = QgsVertexMarker(self.iface.mapCanvas())
            data = s.recv(SIZE)
            data1 = s.recv(SIZE)
            c = data.decode()
            d = data1.decode()
            x = float(c)
            y = float(d)
            print("printing X :", x)
            print("printing Y :", y)
            rect = QgsRectangle(float(x)-scale, float(y)-scale, float(x)+scale, float(y)+scale)
            me = self.iface.mapCanvas()
            me.setExtent(rect)
            me.refresh()
            m.setCenter(QgsPointXY(x, y))
            m.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
            m.setIconSize(7)
            m.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_X)  # or ICON_CROSS, ICON_X
            m.setPenWidth(3)

        else:
            print('Unchecked going to close socket')
            s.close()
```

A sender computer send the lat/long values & **this program** marks the lat/long values on map canvas it happens when my toggle button is checked that's good. But when i make it unchecked by calling socket **close()** method why its not closing the socket (even it prints else part **'Unchecked going to close socket'** but s.close() not closing the socket).

Comment: From the docs *[Note close() releases the resource associated with a connection but does not necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close the connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before close()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close)*

Comment: @user2856 when i am using s.shutdown(1) before s.close its showing error-OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Basically it's closing the socket.in shutdown(1) what the parameter 1 here what its means.

Comment: @user2856 Still some improvement i want in my code. when i first time checked my toggle button it doing his work and when i press button 2nd time to unchecked  it stops(it close the sockets by s.shutdown(1) & s.close()) that's good but when i press on my toggle button 3rd time to make it again checked QGIS hangs and not responding why its happening. After pressing 3rd time it should checked and do its work further.

Comment: I think you should ask on Stack Overflow as this question has no GIS component. You have pyqgis tags, but socket is not part of pyqgis, it's part of the python standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add an answer here because I already implements something like this
in a QGIS plugin but as @user2856 says in comments, this question is
better suited for StackOverflow as it is not related to specific GIS
problems...

You might get better results by using the toogled signal of your action and put your logic in the callback.

Something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
def initGui(self):
    [...]
    self.iconAction.toggled.connect(self.icon_action_handler)

def icon_action_handler(self):
    if self.iconAction.isChecked():
        self.start_socket_and_show_markers() # a function to start the socket (better to run it in a different thread) and show the marker you receive
    else:
        self.close_socket() # a function to close the socket
```

In addition, you probably need to run the socket listener in a different thread (look at Qthread) to avoid QGIS hanging.

Comment: I don't know about Qthread i am beginner in  python can you tell me exactly what should i add in my code to work properly like earlier i mentioned in comments.

Comment: this is a good start point with examples to work with Qthread in QGIS plugin.https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2013/12/07/multithreading-in-qgis-python-plugins/