# Running non blocking python script in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I am new to python programming with QGIS.

I'm looking for a solution to start in QGIS a socket client to receive continuously data from a server which sends telegrams with point data if an event occurs. The points should be then visualized and updated on a temporary layer.
In a standalone python script the socket client runs in an endless loop and processes the data until it's interrupted with + or the sever stops.
If I start the script in the QGIS python console, it blocks the application until the server connection breaks.

How do I run such a script in QGIS, which doesn't block the program itself?

Comment: Look at [`QTask`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307631/2856)

Comment: Many thanks user2856. That‘s what I was looking for.

Comment: related : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311588/toggle-unchecked-button-is-not-closing-the-socket-qgis/311653#311653. In the past, I use `QThread` to do the exact same thing but `QgsTask` seems to be the way to go!